# Restricting scope of Style to grand-child from child in Angular 2?

Tags: css, angular, angular2-template

Here is the structure.

```
<parent>
    <child>
        <grand-child>
        ........
        </grand-child>
    </child>
</parent>
```

Now, my parent has main global css stylesheet with bootstrap and all color-palettes. In my child, I gave another stylesheet with ViewEncapsulation.Emulated to scope it. But my Grand child takes css of parent and not child. Even though, according to hierarchy child is grand-child's parent. What to do if I want grand-child to take the styles of child and not parent.

parent.css

```
button{
background: red none;
}
```

So every button should be red let's say.

my child is the admin-console. So its a whole new look and feel.

child.css

```
button{
background: gray none;
}
```

grand-child.component.html has a button. So I expect it would be gray as it is scoped inside child. But it becomes red.

Comment: Please add the styles to your question.

Comment: Added the explanation and demo what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @ParthChokshi We need to see your actual code / markup that is relevant to the issue. Check out [mcve] for more info on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your styles should work as they are but adding `:host` might be worth a try:

```
:host button {
  background: red none;
}
```

```
:host button {
  background: gray none;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Adding host to Emulated View works. Thanks.